# Does "ouest" take a different preposition than the other directions?

Tags: grammaire, expressions-idiomatiques, prépositions, articles, indications-de-lieu

> La Grande Île, parfois appelée « l’île Rouge » en référence à la latérite qui colore ses plateaux, s’étire sur 1 580 km du nord au sud et 500 km d'est en ouest avec un maximum à 575 km.

I'm noting the difference there between “*du nord au sud*” and “*d'est en ouest*”. Why isn't it “*d'est à l'ouest*”?

Comment: It's the same with *est* actually: “*d'ouest en est*”. How bizarre.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

« D'est en ouest » is an idiom, but directions use an article (*le / l'*) in all other contexts. Therefore, *de nord en sud* is totally unheard, as would any other mixed things like *d'est à l'ouest*.

To make it clearer, here's an equivalent for north–south :

> *from north to south* >>> *du nord au sud* (only possibility)

and east–west :

> *from east to west* >>> *d'est en ouest* (first possibility, using the idiom)
>
> *from east to west* >>> *de l'est à l'ouest* (second possibility, *regular* way, though rarer)

Comment: But they translate as "from north to south" and "from east to west," correct?

Comment: Yes. Regular in english but irregular in french because of the idiom. But it could very well be *de l'est à l'ouest*, which remains a valid possibility.

Comment: Would it be unusual to say that, as opposed to the idiomatic phrasing?

Comment: Unusual, yes, or let's say less used, but it wouldn't sound odd to anyone, I guess...

Comment: De bas en haut. Du sud-est au nord-ouest. De gauche à droite. Du centre à la périphérie. De l'intérieur vers l'extérieur. D'avant en arrière. De la tête à la queue. D'amont en aval. Il y a une règle ?

Comment: Hmm...it almost seems like there is...but it's subtle...

Comment: @Gilles: *en* always precedes a vowel sound.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez No: *de haut en bas*.

Comment: @Gilles: Ok, But in this case the hiatus would come before (“du haut au bas”). My hypothesis may still stand?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I think you can only omit the definite article from a small, frozen set of expressions, and *à* becomes *en* for a small subset. I'm not convinced that there's a grammatical or etymological rule for the use of *en*, rather than happenstance in each instance.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez En retombant là dessus par hasard, je crois qu'il y a une règle. Certains mots, avec l'article défini, désignent par défaut l'extrêmité : « le haut », c'est tout en haut, il faut une expression pour « vers le haut » pour désigner la direction. Donc « du bas au haut » (sonne mal ?) signifierait de tout en bas à tout en haut, alors que « de haut en bas » (sans article) signifie un mouvement vertical ascendant. De/en a l'air réservé à des expressions figées : « du centre à la périphérie » va de l'extrême à l'extrème et on ne pourrait pas utiliser de/en pour exprimer _centrifuge_.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Vieux motard que jamais.

Comment: @Gilles. I didn't remember about any of this discussion. After reading this again, I do somewhat agree with the point you make. Though i still can't see how it explains "d'est en ouest" vs "du nord vers le sud" (while *de l'est vers l'ouest* is probably not as common and *de nord en sud* likely unattested). Maybe those phrases have been shaped by both semantic and phonetic considerations?